# Is there any way to increase the UI size in Anno 1404?

Tags: pc, anno-1404

Trying to play on a 1440p 27 inch screen and the UI doesn’t scale by default to high res so it’s incredibly small and unplayable.

Please note I don’t consider decreasing resolution to be an answer, I have tried playing at 1080p and 720p and it is still too small and at 720p too blurry to read.